# Why should I avoid using the Dispatcher?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding

I've read many thread posts, articles etc. about binding and the thread affinity of GUI controls. There are some post in which the people don't want to use the `Dispatcher`.

I also have a workmate who avoids using the Dispatcher in his code. I asked him for the reason but his answer didn't satisfy me. He said, he don't like such kind of "magic" hidden in a class.

Well I'm a fan of the following class.

```
public class BindingBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private Dispatcher Dispatcher
   {
#if SILVERLIGHT
      get { return Deployment.Current.Dispatcher; }
#else
      get { return Application.Current.Dispatcher; }
#endif
   }

   protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
   {
      var memberExpr = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;
      string property = memberExpr.Member.Name;

      var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
      if (propertyChanged == null) return;

      if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
         propertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
      else
         Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => RaisePropertyChanged(expr));
   }
}
```

Here is the question. Are there any reasons why some people don't want to use such a class? Perhaps I have to reconsider this approach.

You have to admit, there is one strange thing. `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` is excluded from Intellisense. Perhaps they are a bit scary due to this fact.

Regards

**EDIT:**

Ok, another example. Consider a complex object. The collection as example was perhaps not the best idea.

```
public class ExampleVm : BindingBase
{
   private BigFatObject _someData;
   public BigFatObject SomeData
   {
      get { return _someData; }
      set
      {
         _someData = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged(() => SomeData);
      }
   }

   public ExampleVm()
   {
      new Action(LoadSomeData).BeginInvoke(null, null); //I know - it's quick and dirty
   }

   private void LoadSomeData()
   {
      // loading some data from somewhere ...
      // result is of type BigFatObject

      SomeData = result; // This would not work without the Dispatcher, would it?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am also, personally, not against of `Dispatcher` in view model classes. I haven't seen any significant problems with it, yet it gives the most flexibility to your code.

But I like the idea of encapsulating the usage of `Dispatcher` in the infrastructure code as much as possible. Just like you did with `RaisePropertyChanged` method (BTW, in case of `RaisePropertyChanged` you don't have to dispatch anything - binding already does it for you; you only have to dispatch changes to collections).

The biggest and the only disadvantage that I see here is unit testing. Things can get tricky when you try to test your logic that involves usage of `Dispatcher`. Imagine if you had code something like this in a view model:

```
private void UpdateMyCollection() 
{
   IList<ModelData> dataItems = DataService.GetItems();

   // Update data on UI
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
      foreach (ModelData dataItem in dataItems)
      {
         MyObservableCollection.Add(new DataItemViewModel(dataItem));
      }
   }));
}
```

This kind of code is quite typical when it comes to updating collections from a non-UI thread. Now, how would you write a unit test that tests the logic of adding items to the observable collection? First of all, you will need to mock the `Dispatcher` property because `Application.Current` is `null` during unit test execution. Second of all, how will you mock it? Will you create a special thread that will mimic a UI thread and use the `Dispatcher` of that thread? So, this kind of things.

The bottom line is that if you want your code to be unit-test-friendly, you need to think of the way how you will mock the `Dispatcher`. This is the only concern.

**Update:**

The second example you provided WILL work without `Dispatcher` (binding will do the trick).

Comment: "(BTW, in case of RaisePropertyChanged you don't have to dispatch anything - binding already does it for you; you only have to dispatch changes to collections)" Well if this is true then something has been changed since .Net 3.5. Consider a collection which is loaded in a seperated thread and then passed by this thread to a property in a ViewModel. I don't think that's possible without a <code>Dispatcher</code> or a <code>BackGroundWorker</code>.

Comment: I don't understand why there are disadvantages during unit test. Can you explain this a litte more, please?

Comment: @DHN - See my update for an example of trouble with unit tests. As for "Consider a collection which is loaded in a seperated thread and then passed by this thread to a property in a ViewModel" I explicitly mentioned that "you only have to dispatch changes to collections", so, yes, you need to use `Dispatcher` to modify collections, but not usual properties (i.e. you don't have to raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' event on the UI thread, but you have to raise `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` on the UI thread).

Comment: Please see my edit. I think you're right with the collections.

Comment: +1 I agree. From what I recall, I added a (Application.Current != null) test in my VM base classes as a work around for unit testing.

Comment: Regarding your update: Well I've to test it. I seem to recall that my described scenario caused a "CrossThreadException". Your argument regarding unit testing is good. I'll keep it in mind. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. Unfortunately, I didn't have the time to test your statement about the Dispatcher in properties. I'll give an update... To bad that's not possible to give you the votes you deserve.